# Regex for 'hr min sec' time format in shell scripting?

Tags: regex, grep, time-format

In my `build.xml` file I want to extract time using regex in shell scripting which will be in `d hr d min d sec` format.
And time will not always be in same pattern it will differ for eg:

```
1 sec

1 min

2 min 3 sec

4 hr 5 min
```

Now I want to use regular expression to get the time value from my file.
In the xml file it will be in value tag:

```
<value>1 hr 54 min</value>
```

I used     `cat build.xml | grep -oP '(?<=<value>).*sec?(?=</value>)'`
but in this case it will print only for sec or likewise I can print only for min.

Please help me in this regex.

Comment: Don't use `cat`.  Do it as `grep -oP 'pattern' build.xml`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about this?

```
echo '<value>4 hr 3 sec</value>' 
| grep -oP '(?<=<value>)(\d+\s+hr)?(\s*\d+\s+min)?(\s*\d+\s+sec)?(?=</value>)'

4 hr 3 sec

echo '<value>3 sec</value>' |
 grep -oP '(?<=<value>)(\d+\s+hr)?(\s*\d+\s+min)?(\s*\d+\s+sec)?(?=</value>)'

3 sec
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
(?<=<value>)(\\d+ (hr|min|sec) ?){1,3}(?=</value>)
```

It's not exactly prescriptive (for example it allows "3 hr 4 hr"), but it should be good enough to work for you.

Comment: No not working....In that xml file I have more than one <value> tags for strings, ints and time.